# Get frames from video, edit and save in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, video

I am referring this [application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/v1-golf/id349715369?mt=8) and want to learn that how can we create like this?

Actually there is the major R&D task for me and I don't even know what to search in this topic.

I don't know , from where to start googling.

According to my understandings, the concepts is, It is getting all frames from video as Image and edit it like draw line on it and then save it, so once video is played it also contains that editing.

I had referred this [iFrameExtractor](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor) but can't got success.

Please advise me how to start doing R&D on this topic..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have a answer for your question, First of all u have to get all video from your iPhone. That can be done using ALAssetLibrary after that u have to how thee videos in UITableView. I think that should be easy for u. After selecting a video from a table view u have to play that selected video using MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer. After that u have to draw anything.There are number of methods of drawing anything on Videos which are:-

UIBezierPathCurve, UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, Open GLes etc etc

Thats it.try googling on it. thanks :)

Comment: How to achieve flip feature of video in ios ?